# How to delete the specific lines that starts and ends with specific string in a file in java?

Tags: java

I have a file abc.txt that has lines as

### abc.txt

```
Ethernet 1/1 

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3

abs_mod_
jjj
kkkk
ll
abs_mod_

interface 6

interface 7
```

I want to delete the lines in between abs_mod_ and also lines starting with abs_mod_

the final output should be

### abc.txt

```
Ethernet 1/1

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3

interface 6

interface 7
```

I have tried how to read the file line by line.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("abc.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("abc.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            boolean flag = true;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("abs_mod_")){
                    if(flag)    flag = false;
                    else        flag = true;
                }else if(flag){
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString().replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using regex:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("abc.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(
                stringBuffer
                .toString()
                .trim()
                .replaceAll("[\\n]+(abs_mod_)(\\s|\\S)*(abs_mod_)", "")
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to show double space between interface 3 and 6

Comment: @Hulk check the output now.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the spaces  like this System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString().replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")); I just want to print the next line from the removed lines

Comment: @Hulk You could either do that using regex or store each line in an ArrayList and delete the ones you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Load the entire file into memory, then use regex to remove the lines you don't want.

*Using Java 11+*

```
String text = Files.readString(Paths.get("abc.txt"));
text = text.replaceAll("(?sm)^abs_mod_(?:.*?^abs_mod_)?.*?\\R", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

*Using Java 7+*

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("abc.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
text = text.replaceAll("(?sm)^abs_mod_(?:.*?^abs_mod_)?.*?\\R", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

*Output*

```
Ethernet 1/1 

Ethernet 1/2

interface 3


interface 6

interface 7
```

*Explanation*

```
(?              Set flags:
  s               DOTALL     '.' matches any character, including a line terminator
  m               MULTILINE  '^' and '$' match just after/before a line terminator
)
^abs_mod_       Match 'abs_mod_' at beginning of line
(?:             Start optional non-capturing group
  .*?             Match any text (including line terminators) until:
  ^abs_mod_         Match 'abs_mod_' at beginning of line
)?              End optional section
.*?             Match any text up to:
\R                Match line terminator
```

Both `.*` have the extra `?` making them "reluctant", so they don't cross the "ending" match. The `.` in the second `.*?` won't actually match a line terminator since the ending match *is* a line terminator.

The optional section is because you said: *"delete the lines in between `abs_mod_` and **also lines starting with** `abs_mod_`"*

The regex is really these two blended together:

```
(?sm)^abs_mod_.*?^abs_mod_.*?\R   Lines between lines starting with 'abs_mod_' (inclusive)
(?m:^)abs_mod_.*\R                Single line starting with 'abs_mod_'
```

Comment: I want the output to be in java 8. Please help

Comment: can you explain the regex pattern you have applied in the code

Comment: @Hulk Already gave you Java 8 version. Do you know regex? If not, you need to learn it first, as StackOverflow is not a teaching site. If yes, which part of the regex don't you understand?

Comment: text.replaceAll("(?sm)^abs_mod_(.*?^abs_mod_)?.*?\\R", ""). This Regex pattern

Comment: @Hulk If you know regex, you should understand most of it, so *which part* of it don't you understand? `(?sm)`? Use of `^` in the middle? `\\R`? `.*?`? What?

Comment: entire regex..I am not any getting idea on any part of regex

Comment: @Andrews thanks for explanation...I want in the place of removed text remaining lines without any line break...as it showing some line break between interface 3 and 6 (double space). Please help

Comment: @Hulk Add `+` at the end of the regex.